# Which is better to use <b> or <strong> for SEO?

Tags: seo, html

I've been coding for a while and it's just struck me, what's better to use in terms of SEO:

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

or

```
<strong>Hello</strong>
```

Comment: Valid question, but people who worry about this level of minutia should have the rest of their site ***absolutely*** perfect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Matt Cutts are treated exactly the same. FYI, `<i>` and `<em>` are also treated the same.

[Video where Matt Cutts says they have the same weight](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-1756437348670651505&ei=FbKRSaWVEpKwqwLO8bzHCw&q=strong%20tag&hl=en)

Comment: I would never think to even question this! Too busy trying to write good quality content to go in between the tags....

Comment: Sweet source for the answer, direct from the horse's mouth.

Comment: @Tchalvak - that's always the best way with SEO. Unfortunately we don't get too many chances to do that.

Answer (score 1):

John is right, but `<b>` denotes the way it should look like instead of the meaning like `<strong>`. The same with `<i>`, you are saying that text should be in *italics* but, with `<em>` you are making emphasis on that text.